# Heroku Built-in(TouchID) doesn't work & don't have 1-time password generator setup

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

My mac brokedown.Thus, I can't use the touchID to verify myself anymore on heroku. Thus, the only other option is to use 1-time password generator which I don't even have it setup & you need to login (and verify) to be able to setup. What shall I do? How can I gain access to my heroku account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Heroku recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/built-in-authenticators) having a back-up in place:

> We recommend registering another verification method to ensure that you can log in to Heroku on other devices where a built-in authenticator is not present.

[and](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/recovery-codes):

> Recovery codes provide an important backup if your usual MFA verification method is not available. For example, if you normally use Salesforce Authenticator but forget your mobile phone one day, you can still log in using a recovery code. Generate a list of ten single-use recovery codes that you can keep in a safe place until you need them.

This is always a good idea when using MFA with any service.

If you do not have another authentication method registered and you don't have recovery codes, [you'll have to ask for help](https://help.heroku.com/GVXHJTX0/mfa-lost-verifier). How you do that depends on whether you're a member of an enterprise account:

> **Registering multiple MFA verification methods is strongly recommended.**
>
> **If you’re a member of a Heroku Enterprise Account** and need help with recovering access when your MFA verification method isn’t available:
>
> - Your Enterprise Account admin can generate a temporary verification code that allows you to log in to your account (starting August 2021)
> - You can contact support for help.
>
> **If you're not a member of a Heroku Enterprise Account:**
>
> - e-mail account-lockout@heroku.com for help.
>
> **We may request additional information to recover access to ensure that an attacker is not attempting to access your account.**

Comment: Thank so much for the support Chris. I was hoping if there's a hack or leeway that the dev community has used until hearing back. Nonetheless, with respect to security, I believe those are the only option.

Comment: I imagine that this is a stressful experience, @Daniyaldehleh. But recovering an account _should_ be difficult. If it were easier, MFA wouldn't have much value as a security measure. Hopefully Heroku is able to help you soon.