# I lost my 2-factor auth app and I can't login into my heroku account

Tags: heroku, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I had to factory reset my phone and I lost my two factor auth app (Google Authenticator) and now I can't login into my heroku account

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku Built-in(TouchID) doesn't work & don't have 1-time password generator setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138148/heroku-built-intouchid-doesnt-work-dont-have-1-time-password-generator-set)

Comment: (TL;DR, you need to talk to Heroku support. [We can't answer customer support questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577).)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I guess this post is long out of date, but I have a similar problem - Google Auth apparently changed and locked me out so I can't access my heroku account.  I've been through loads of emails with heroku support who've been really unhelpful & asked me for specific info I can only get if I log in to my heroku account!  I'm gonna have to close my account now as there's no way to get back into it.  Really bad on heroku's part that they can't just allow us to reset the auth app we use with our username & password - this seems crazy!  It seems not that uncommon - esp with Google Auth