# How to retrieve my heroku credentials in authenticator

Tags: heroku

I happened to integrate my heroku account with the authenticator, I recently changed my phone and restored the old one, I can't access my heroku account because I lost the authenticator passwords

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku Built-in(TouchID) doesn't work & don't have 1-time password generator setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138148/heroku-built-intouchid-doesnt-work-dont-have-1-time-password-generator-set)

Answer (score 1):

Try to contact with heroku support, they may can retrieve your account after you proove that you are legitimate.